# cannot find easy_install after updating setuptools

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, setuptools, easy-install

On a AWS machine, I updated pip to version 9.0.1 with

```
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then updated setuptools from 12.2 to 36.2.2 doing :

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

But now I can't use easy_install anymore, it says

```
-bash: /usr/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory
```

I saw that there is only easy_install-3.4 in /usr/bin, how can I retrieve easy_install?

My problem is that I wanted to create a .egg file and apparently with the old version of setuptools it was not created correctly so when I was installing it via easy_install I couldn't import the package in Python ('no module named xxx').

I am using Python 2.7

Thanks

Comment: 2.7.x => what is `x`? I would assume it is 2.7.6?

Comment: It is Python 2.7.12